# What does C Drive or T Drive means?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

When I watching the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXdpCRgR-xE&index=2&list=PL0eyrZgxdwhwBToawjm9faF1ixePexft-),

at the time <kbd>1:15</kbd>

> you know C Drive or T Drive wherever you did actually install it and ...

What does `C Drive` and `T Drive` mean?

[image]

Does them means `Disk C` and `Disk D`?

Comment: This is very off topic and should be moved. However, the C drive is usually the main hard drive and T is probably a network disk. Look at the left side and scroll down to see which drives you have or are connected to.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with the English language.  https://superuser.com would be the appropriate site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does.

According to Cambridge Dictionary

**[drive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/drive)** [noun] [computing]

> a device for storing computer information

Usually, you install applications in a partition, a logical part, of your [hard disk drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive). Notice the use of both words: disk and drive. An HDD is a **device** (drive) implemented by a magnetic **disk**. Depending on your configuration it will be labeled C, D or whatever.